# Ant build classpath jar generates "error in opening zip file"

Tags: eclipse, ant, build, zip

I have a project built in eclipse with a dependencies on 3rd party jars. I'm trying to generate a suitable build file for ant - using eclipses built-in export->ant buildfile feature as a starting block.

When I run the build target I get the following error:

```
[javac] error: error reading /base/repo/FabTrace/lib/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-j2ee-management_1.0_spec/1.0/geronimo-j2ee-management_1.0_spec-1.0.jar; error in opening zip file
```

And the whole build file (auto-generated by eclipse) looks like this:
(NB: the error above always references the first jar listed in the classpath)

```
<project basedir="." default="build" name="FabTrace">
    <property environment="env"/>
    <property name="ECLIPSE_HOME" value="/opt/apps/eclipse"/>
    <property name="debuglevel" value="source,lines,vars"/>
    <property name="target" value="1.5"/>
    <property name="source" value="1.5"/>
    <path id="JUnit 4.libraryclasspath">
        <pathelement location="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins/org.junit4_4.5.0.v20090824/junit.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins/org.hamcrest.core_1.1.0.v20090501071000.jar"/>
    </path>
    <path id="FabTrace.classpath">
        <pathelement location="bin"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-j2ee-management_1.0_spec/1.0/geronimo-j2ee-management_1.0_spec-1.0.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-jms_1.1_spec/1.0/geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.0.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2/commons-collections-3.2.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/commons-io/commons-io/1.4/commons-io-1.4.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.1/commons-lang-2.1.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1/commons-logging-1.1.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/commons-logging/commons-logging-api/1.1/commons-logging-api-1.1.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/javax/activation/activation/1.1/activation-1.1.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/javax/jms/jms/1.1/jms-1.1.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/javax/mail/mail/1.4/mail-1.4.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.1/jaxb-api-2.1.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/javax/xml/stream/stax-api/1.0-2/stax-api-1.0-2.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/junit/junit/4.4/junit-4.4.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/log4j/log4j/1.2.15/log4j-1.2.15.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/apache/camel/camel-jms-2.0-M1.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/spring/spring-2.5.6.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/apache/camel/camel-bundle-2.0-M1.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/backport-util-concurrent/backport-util-concurrent-3.1.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/commons-pool/commons-pool-1.4.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/apache/camel/camel-activemq-1.1.0.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/apache/activemq/activemq-camel-5.2.0.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/jencks/jencks-2.2-all.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/jencks/jencks-amqpool-2.2.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/activemq/apache-activemq-5.3.1/activemq-all-5.3.1.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/activemq/apache-activemq-5.3.1/lib/optional/xbean-spring-3.6.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/activemq/apache-activemq-5.3.1/lib/activemq-core-5.3.1.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/activemq/apache-activemq-5.3.1/lib/camel-jetty-2.2.0.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/activemq/apache-activemq-5.3.1/lib/web/jetty-6.1.9.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/activemq/apache-activemq-5.3.1/lib/web/jetty-util-6.1.9.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/activemq/apache-activemq-5.3.1/lib/web/jetty-xbean-6.1.9.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/activemq/apache-activemq-5.3.1/lib/optional/activemq-optional-5.3.1.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/activemq/apache-activemq-5.3.1/lib/web/geronimo-servlet_2.5_spec-1.2.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/activemq/apache-activemq-5.3.1/lib/optional/spring-beans-2.5.6.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/activemq/apache-activemq-5.3.1/lib/optional/spring-context-2.5.6.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/activemq/apache-activemq-5.3.1/lib/optional/spring-core-2.5.6.jar"/>
        <path refid="JUnit 4.libraryclasspath"/>
    </path>
    <target name="init">
        <mkdir dir="bin"/>
        <copy includeemptydirs="false" todir="bin">
            <fileset dir="src/main/java">
                <exclude name="**/*.launch"/>
                <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
        <copy includeemptydirs="false" todir="bin">
            <fileset dir="src/test/java">
                <exclude name="**/*.launch"/>
                <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
        <copy includeemptydirs="false" todir="bin">
            <fileset dir="config">
                <exclude name="**/*.launch"/>
                <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>
    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="bin"/>
    </target>
    <target depends="clean" name="cleanall"/>
    <target depends="build-subprojects,build-project" name="build"/>
    <target name="build-subprojects"/>
    <target depends="init" name="build-project">
        <echo message="${ant.project.name}: ${ant.file}"/>
        <javac debug="true" debuglevel="${debuglevel}" destdir="bin" source="${source}" target="${target}">
            <src path="src/main/java"/>
            <classpath refid="FabTrace.classpath"/>
        </javac>
        <javac debug="true" debuglevel="${debuglevel}" destdir="bin" source="${source}" target="${target}">
            <src path="src/test/java"/>
            <classpath refid="FabTrace.classpath"/>
        </javac>
        <javac debug="true" debuglevel="${debuglevel}" destdir="bin" source="${source}" target="${target}">
            <src path="config"/>
            <classpath refid="FabTrace.classpath"/>
        </javac>
    </target>

</project>
```

(I know there's eclipse specific stuff in here. But I get the same results with or without it.)

I've done ye old google search and trawled around without success.

I can confirm that all the jars do really exist. I've also tried from the commandline and as sudo - again, same results.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Is the jar file valid? Can you open it in a WinZip or other compression tool?

Comment: Sigh. I'd figured that because I'd removed the first jars that originally caused this problem (I wasn't even convinced I really needed them any more) and the problem just moved to the next jar... well, that made me suspicious of a systemic fault.

Turns out I did in fact have aload of garbage jars on the classpath. Must have screwed up a download or something at some point.

Anyway, all fixed now. Cheers

Comment: Why not move your comment to an answer and then accept it?  This might prove to be a useful question for someone, but at the moment it shows as 'unanswered'.

Comment: @AlastairBrayne Facing the exact same problem. Nothing worked till now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Martin Clayton's suggestions, my previous comment is copied below as an answer.

"Sigh. I'd figured that because I'd removed the first jars that originally caused this problem (I wasn't even convinced I really needed them any more) and the problem just moved to the next jar... well, that made me suspicious of a systemic fault. Turns out I did in fact have aload of garbage jars on the classpath. Must have screwed up a download or something at some point. Anyway, all fixed now. Cheers"

Comment: I had loads of hidden jars (.!79974!google-play-services.jar) causing the issue, thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a `<filterset/>` in any of the copy statements in your build file? I ran into an issue once where I was `<copy>`-ing "`**/*`" and towards the end of development I figured out how to use `<filterset/>` with `<copy>`.

To make a long story short, the text replacement worked flawlessly, however any binary file, executable or .jar that was in that "`**/*`" path was totally destroyed. Instead of opening files in binary mode, they get opened in text mode, and then saved in text mode.

If you do have a `<filterset/>`, or something similar anywhere in your build file, make sure to `<exclude/>` any and all binary files.